# Get ActionName, ControllerName and AreaName and pass it in ActionFilter Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, action-filter, authorize-attribute

I use a custom AuthorizationFilter like the followings:

```
public class ActionAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext) {

        if(!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        if(IsUserExcluded())
            return false;
        else
            return IsRoleAuthorize(httpContext);
    }
}
```

I use this filter at the top of each action I have, and for check Is Authorized, need Action Name, Controller Name, And Area Name. So is there any way to get this names in `AuthorizeCore()` method like use `System.Web.HttpContextBase`? if answer is No then how can I get this names and pass it to attribute, obviously I don't want to add each name by hand, actually something like`ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]` in controllers:

```
[ActionAuthorize(actionName=Action, controller=ControllerName, area=AreaName)]
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}
```

Does any one have any idea about it?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You could fetch them from the RouteData:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
    string currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
    string currentController = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
    string currentArea = rd.Values["area"] as string;

    ...

}
```

Comment: "You could fetch them from the RouteData" Isn't a good answer. **Now** it was edited, I'll revert.

Comment: This could be just in ASP.NET MVC 4, but the area is found in rd.DataTokens["area"].

Comment: You should change the line var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData; to  
  var rd = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData; better to use the standard one than a parameter :)

Comment: @AndersM., I would rather not do that. That would render my code extremely unit-test unfriendly. I always prefer working with abstractions. Can't remember when I last used `HttpContext.Current` in my career.

Comment: The area name will not be contained in the Values RouteValueDictionary. Rather, it will be contained in the DataTokens property, so to get the area you would want rd.DataTokens["area"] as string

Answer (score 1):

Face the same issue just a moment ago and my solution is:

1. Define 2 attributes in your ActionAuthorizeAttribute class e.g.

   ```
   public string ControllerName {get;set;}
   public string ActionName {get;set;}
   ```
2. While annotating your action of the controller specify them e.g.

   ```
   [ActionAuthorize(Roles="Admin", ContollerName="ControllerName",ActionName="ActionName")]**
   public ActionResult Disable(int id)
   {
    ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the area will not work if you are on a custom filter
the next will work to get an area

```
filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> namespace dene.kontroller {
>     public class daAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
>     {
>         private Entities db = new Entities();
>         private readonly string[] allowedroles;
>         public daAttribute(params string[] roles)
>         {
>             this.allowedroles = roles;
>         }
> 
> 
>         protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
>         {
>             bool authorize = false;
>             foreach (var role in allowedroles)
>             {
>                 if (role == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
>                 {
>                      
>                     if (role!= null)
>                     {
>                         authorize = true;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 
> 
>             }
>             return authorize;
>         }
> 
> 
>         protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
>         {
> 
>             FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
>             filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
>         }
> 
>     } }
```

Answer (score 0):

If getting the **area** did not work, you can fetch are from the **RouteData** in this way:

```
 string currentArea = string.Empty;
 if (rd.DataTokens.TryGetValue("area", out object area))
 {
     currentArea = area.ToString();
 }
```