# override AuthorizeCore in asp.net mvc core identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to get `Area RouthData` inside `AuthorizationHandlerContext` .
I found this answer [fetch area from the RouteData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976760/9587283) ,  so I need to override `AuthorizeCore` like

```
public class ActionAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        string currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
        string currentController = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
        string currentArea = rd.Values["area"] as string;
    }
}
```

But unfortunately , I got this error

> 'ActionAuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase)':not suitable method found to overried

How can I override AuthorizeCore properly ?

Answer (score -1):

The error is because there is no `AuthorizeCore` method on `AuthorizeAttribute` to override. You can [view the source](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/2.1.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) to see this is clearly the case.

Things are a bit different now in ASP.NET Core, and you're most likely referencing code that applies to ASP.NET MVC. Now, `AuthorizeAttribute` now is mostly just a catch-hold for the authorization middleware, instead of having any direct functionality of its own.

I'm not sure what you're ultimately trying to achieve, but if you're trying to do custom authorization based on something like route data, then you should actually be using [policy auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for that, rather than trying to subclass `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Comment: I just want to pass the `area` from RouthData( as show in code ) , how can I get that ?

Comment: What you mean by "pass"? To what? In a controller action/view you already have access to his via the `HttpContext`/`ViewContext`.

Comment: when using `protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,` , I can get `ControllerName` and `MethodName` from `context` , but I also want to get `ViewName` or `AreaName` from this . That's all I want to get .

Comment: Again, in what context do you need this information? Inside of a controller or view, it's already available. You don't need to set via some other means.