# Get partialview actionname and controllername from AuthorizeCore of overloaded AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I am trying to retrieve the 'action name' and 'controller name' from a custom AuthorizeCore of AuthorizeAttribute.

I have been trying the method here:
[Get ActionName, ControllerName and AreaName and pass it in ActionFilter Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976476/get-actionname-controllername-and-areaname-and-pass-it-in-actionfilter-attributy)
That is to recover the route values from the httpContext.

This doesn't work for PartialViews though:

I have a main view (Say /Enterprise/View), which calls the following sub view (in Razor):

`Html.RenderAction("partialViewContacts", "Enterprise")`

In authorizeCore, the Controller/action provided by httpcontext are always Entreprise/View, and never Enterprise/partialViewContacts.

```
Protected Overrides Function AuthorizeCore(httpContext As HttpContextBase) As Boolean
    Dim authorized As Boolean = isAllowed()
        If Not authorized AndAlso System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("IdUser") IsNot Nothing 
             Dim rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData
             Dim action = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")
             Dim ctrller = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")
             Throw New Exception("Not authorized")
        End If
    Return authorized
End Function
```

This is needed for logging purposes. The AuthorizeCore method itself does work and correctly restricts/authorize access to the request view or partial view.

Comment: did you tried something like this: convert the value to string. ```HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]``` or ```HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]```

Comment: That was an interesting try, but those also hold the main view controller and action values